error in installation of SXT software
I am trying to compile SXT software, of AstroSat mission, but I get the following error when running the command make:
g++ -c -Wno-deprecated -w -pthread TimeDate.cpp -I./include -I../../include -o obj/TimeDate.o
In file included from ../../include/log4cpp/Appender.hh:21,
                 from ../../include/log4cpp/Category.hh:14,
                 from include/SXTMISC.h:17,
                 from TimeDate.cpp:9:
../../include/log4cpp/Priority.hh:107:9: error: ISO C++17 does not allow dynamic exception specifications
  107 |         throw(std::invalid_argument);
      |         ^~~~~
In file included from include/SXTMISC.h:17,
                 from TimeDate.cpp:9:
../../include/log4cpp/Category.hh:116:9: error: ISO C++17 does not allow dynamic exception specifications
  116 |         throw(std::invalid_argument);
      |         ^~~~~
../../include/log4cpp/Category.hh:150:9: error: ISO C++17 does not allow dynamic exception specifications
  150 |         throw(std::invalid_argument);
      |         ^~~~~
In file included from include/SXTMISC.h:20,
                 from TimeDate.cpp:9:
../../include/log4cpp/PropertyConfigurator.hh:48:64: error: ISO C++17 does not allow dynamic exception specifications
   48 |      static void configure(const std::string& initFileName) throw (ConfigureFailure);
      |                                                             ^~~~~

make[2]: *** [Makefile:36: obj/TimeDate.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/merin/Softwares/Astrosat/AS1SXTLevel2-1.5/SXT/src/SXTMISC'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/merin/Softwares/Astrosat/AS1SXTLevel2-1.5/SXT/src'
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 2 

How can I fix this?

Please [edit] your question and link us to where you downloaded this software from. My first guess is that you have a version mismatch but without knowing anything at all about this software, we can't help.

If you're referring to this SXT Pipeline Software then the bottom of the page says "Important Note: G++ 4.8 is needed for SXT PIPELINE. It works only in cent OS 7.1 and Redhat linux systems."
